# Storing File in Cordova App's folder

Tags: android, file, cordova

I want to store a file.
If I use

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("mystorage", {create : true}, function(dataDir) {
 ...
});
```

the file gets stored in `/sdcard/mystorage`. I want to store it in `/data/data/{package name}` instead. How?

Comment: does nobody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please read  [docs for the File plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file) (`org.apache.cordova.file`). Specifically look at the section *Where to Store Files*, in that section defined cross-platform constants where you could store you
files.

Constant which you are asking is `cordova.file.dataDirectory`